# Calculating improper intergal $\displaystyle \int^a_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} dx$

Tags: solution-verification, improper-integrals

I tried to solve the improper integral below, but the answer was $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$. What is wrong with the solution?

$\displaystyle \int^a_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} dx 
= \displaystyle \lim_{p \to a-0} \int^p_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} dx \\
= \displaystyle \frac{1}{a} \lim_{p \to a-0} \int^p_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{a})^2}} dx \\
= \displaystyle \frac{1}{a} \lim_{p \to a-0} \left[ \arcsin{\frac{x}{a}} \right]^p_0 \\
= \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2a}
$

Comment: How is this integral improper? It's bounds are finite

Comment: @RounakSarkar the integrand is unbounded, which is why it's an improper integral

Comment: @peek-a-boo It is Lebesgue integrable and exists as an improper Riemann integral.  Perhaps that is Rounak's point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful about the change of variable. You need to complete the diferential and change the integration limits. Here $u=\frac{x}{a}$ and $du=\frac{dx}{a}$, then

$\displaystyle \int^a_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} dx 
= \displaystyle   \int^a_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{a})^2}} \frac{dx}{a} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\displaystyle   \int^1_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(u)^2}} du \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}.
$

Any doubts?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$u\;=\;\arcsin \frac{x}{a}$$
Then $$du\;=\;\frac{\frac{1}{a}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}\,dx\;=\;\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx$$
We have $$I\;=\; \lim_{t \to a} \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx$$
$$ \;=\; \lim_{t \to a} \int_{0}^t 1\,d(\arcsin \frac{x}{a})$$
$$ \;=\; \lim_{t \to a} \bigg[\arcsin \frac{x}{a}\bigg]_{0}^a \;=\; \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: "I tried to solve the improper integral below, but the answer was $\frac{\pi}{2}$. What is wrong with the solution?" While you've solved the integral, you haven't actually addressed the question.

Comment: You have made a aditional $$\frac{1}{a}$$ there, which should not be.